Parcial Base de Datos 1 (sql) con errores significativos (quiero observaciones)
Hola muy buenas a todos, tengo un [problema]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/0kMhqqFC.png
con el parcial que les estoy proporcionando, y abajo mi resolución a los qerys (bochornosas), llenas de redundancia havings inútiles y confusamente MAX(MAX()).
p1:
    CREATE VIEW PV(NRO, IDL, CANTIDAD, PRECIO) AS
    SELECT D.NRO, D.IDL, D.CANTIDAD, MAX(D.PRECIO)
    FROM DETALLE D
    GROUP BY D.NRO, D.IDL, D.CANTIDAD
    HAVING MAX(D.PRECIO) = (
        SELECT MAX(MAX(D2.PRECIO))
        FROM DETALLE D2
        GROUP BY D2.NRO, D2.IDL, D2.CANTIDAD
    );

p2:
    CREATE VIEW PEPE_SI_COMPRO (IDP, CUIT) AS 
    SELECT L.IDP, C.CUIT 
    FROM CLIENTE C 
    INNER JOIN FACTURA F ON F.CUIT = C.CUIT 
    INNER JOIN DETALLE D ON D.NRO = F.NRO 
    INNER JOIN LOTE L ON L.IDL = D.IDL 
    WHERE C.RAZON_SOCIAL = 'PEPE SRL';

    CREATE VIEW PEPE_NO_COMPRO (IDP) AS 
    SELECT PS.IDP 
    FROM PEPE_SI_COMPRO PS 
    RIGHT JOIN PRODUCTO P ON PS.IDP = P.IDP 
    WHERE PS.CUIT IS NULL;

p3:
    CREATE VIEW LOTE_MAX(STOCKMAX) AS 
    SELECT MAX(L.STOCK) 
    FROM PRODUCTO P 
    INNER JOIN LOTE L ON L.IDP = P.IDP 
    WHERE P.DESCR = 'PEPITOS' 
    HAVING MAX(L.STOCK) = (
        SELECT MAX(MAX(L2.STOCK)) 
        FROM PRODUCTO P2 
        INNER JOIN LOTE L2 ON L2.IDP = P2.IDP 
        WHERE P2.DESCR = 'PEPITOS'
    ;)

    CREATE VIEW LOTE_SEGUNDO_MAX (IDL, STOCK) AS 
    SELECT L.IDL, MAX(L.STOCK) 
    FROM LOTE L 
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTO P ON P.IDP = L.IDP 
    INNER JOIN LOTE_MAX LM ON L.STOCK != LM.STOCKMAX 
    WHERE P.DESCR = 'PEPITOS' 
    HAVING MAX(L.STOCK) = (
        SELECT MAX(MAX(L2.STOCK)) 
        FROM PRODUCTO P2 
        INNER JOIN LOTE L2 ON L2.IDP = P2.IDP 
        WHERE P2.DESCR = 'PEPITOS'
    );

A pesar de todo eso yo quiero saber de gente que este relacionada a base de datos SQL sepa del tema, me pueda decir si de igual forma proporcionarían la información pedida en cada punto.me aseguran que subquerys en el HAVING no son soportados en casi ningún motor de SQL entre otras cosas que me resaltaron. comprendo lo mal que pueden estar solo quiero saber si logran su cometido y con que motores me pueden asegurar que son compatibles, yo tenia entendido que mínimo firebird me lo soportaría, me interesa saber sobre oracle, mysql,sql server. recurro aquí ya que todo lo que se encuentra es en ingles y no comprendo.
Mi objetivo es despejar dudas, ya se que estos qerys no deberían repetirse!! jajaja
MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Creo que estás un poco confundido con lo que dijo. No creo que haya dicho que los subqueries en HAVING no sean soportados, al menos en SQL Server sí son soportados y creo que en otros motores también.
Lo que no es soportado es anidar funciones de agregado, por lo que el MAX(MAX(columna)) que tienes en las subconsultas puede ser un problema.
Más allá de confirmarte si las consultas que hiciste dan el resultado correcto, te proporcionaré opciones más adecuadas. A pesar de que en general pareciera que las consultas podrían regresar el resultado si se corrigen algunos errores de sintaxis, la complejidad haría que el rendimiento sea malo. Al usar bases de datos, queremos eficiencia para evitar que sea un problema cuando crezcan.
--p1: Necesitamos unir con Lote para obtener el identificador del producto
-- No necesitamos agrupar porque buscamos el precio mayor en la subconsulta sin importar a que pertenece
-- En la consulta principal tampoco hace falta agrupar y por eso el HAVING cambia a WHERE.
CREATE VIEW PV 
AS
SELECT  D.NRO, 
        D.IDL, 
        L.IDP, 
        D.PRECIO
FROM DETALLE D
JOIN LOTE    L ON D.IDL = L.IDL
WHERE D.PRECIO = (
    SELECT MAX(D2.PRECIO)
    FROM DETALLE D2
);
GO
--p2: No hace falta crear una vista adicional cuando se puede usar una subconsulta.
-- Esto se puede lograr también con NOT EXISTS, EXCEPT y OUTER JOINs (como lo tenías pero es menos eficiente)
CREATE VIEW PEPE_NO_COMPRO (IDP) AS 
SELECT P.IDP 
FROM PRODUCTO P
WHERE P.IDP NOT IN( SELECT L.IDP
                    FROM LOTE L
                    JOIN DETALLE D ON L.IDL = D.IDL
                    JOIN FACTURA F ON D.NRO = F.NRO
                    JOIN CLIENTE C ON F.CUIT = C.CUIT
                    WHERE C.RAZON_SOCIAL = 'PEPE SRL');
GO
--p3: Esto era más complicado antes de que se extendiera la funcionalidad OFFSET
-- Pero aun sin ella, hay otras formas de hacerlo sin necesidad de funciones de agregado.
CREATE VIEW LOTE_MAX AS 
SELECT L.*
FROM PRODUCTO P 
INNER JOIN LOTE L ON L.IDP = P.IDP 
WHERE P.DESCR = 'PEPITOS' 
ORDER BY STOCK DESC OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
GO

Existen otras maneras de hacerlo, pero pueden depender de cada motor de base de datos y me parece que todas estas cumplen con el estándar SQL sin usar instrucciones específicas de alguno.
Por cierto, para alardear de muchos años de experiencia, el diseño de las tablas que usó para el parcial es horrible.

Luis, te agradezco mucho el tiempo que me dedicaste. Voy a guardar tus resoluciones para tener de referencia y acercarme a un sql mas directo y limpio. con mucha caradurez me voy a llorarle la carta al docente, gracias! muy buenas tus qerys y sus comentarios, queda clarisimo.
